# The walls in our living room transitions into the ceiling with a curved surface...what is this called?

Tags: walls, ceiling

Our living room has walls that transitions into the ceiling with a curved surface...the radius of the curve is a few inches I think.

What is this kind of construction called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the radius of the wall to ceiling transition is on the order of 1 to 2 inches then that corner is likely formed by use of a vinyl inside corner beading. It comes in lengths and inserted up into the corners and nailed / screwed along the edges through a flange that gets covered over with a feathered edge of drywall mud to blend the beading to the wall and ceiling surfaces.

Sometimes a wood material is also used that looks similar to a cove moulding but that would more than likely not be used up against the drywall in a mudded in smooth transition.

In decades gone by it was sometimes popular to create much larger radius transitions that could be a radius of 6 to 8 inches (maybe even more). These would be seen on plaster construction where curved backer corners were installed to the wall/ceiling lathe and then additional wood lathe was attached to these to create the curved surface. A professional plasterer would then plaster the wall and curved transition up to the ceiling all in one continuous process. Sorry that I cannot provide a name for that type of construction.

Comment: +1 I think they are simply called [*cove ceilings*](http://www.houzz.com/cove-ceiling).

Comment: @bib is exactly right. Further, Cove ceilings were expecially popular in houses built in the 1950s and 60s.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I once heard them called "trey" or " tray" ceilings?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. [Trey ceilings](http://info.stantonhomes.com/bid/103249/14-Trey-Ceiling-Designs-for-2014-Trey-Ceiling-Photos-and-Ideas) have stepped, raised areas; that isn't what the OP is describing.